# Implicit numerical ODE solvers: still unconditionally stable if Newton iterations limited?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, simulation, runge-kutta-methods, implicit-function

Implicit ODE solvers like Backward Euler are often described as unconditionally stable, which I believe means that the solution never blows up regardless of how large the solver step size is chosen.

But implicit solvers like Backward Euler rely on iterative numerical methods like Newton-Raphson, which can in some cases take very many iterations to properly converge on a solution, and which could easily fail, e.g., if the solution is near a discontinuity.

When implicit solvers are described as unconditionally stable, is this assuming that an unlimited number of iterations is allowed and that the solution is in a well-behaved region (e.g., without discontinuities)?

More specifically, if the number of Newton iterations is fixed to 2 (meaning that two iterations are always done at each time step and then the solver moves on regardless of the error remaining in the solution), does Backward Euler remain unconditionally stable?

If the equation system happens to be challenging so that 70 iterations are required for accurate solution, say, is the solution still guaranteed to not blow up with a limit of 2 iterations?

I know that accuracy would likely suffer if more than more than 2 iterations are required, but here I'm only interested in whether the solution blows up by virtue of limiting the number of iterations so severely.

Many thanks for entertaining this non-mathematician's question and for sharing an answer if you have one!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea of stability is that if an exact ODE solution converges (quickly, transiently) towards a stable configuration (that might be slowly changing) then the numerical solution does the same and stays converged in this sense. This can and will depend on the size of the numerical steps.

This general idea is not easy to translate into formal terms. As always it is easiest to apply to linear systems. As these decouple via diagonalization into scalar complex-valued equations, it is sufficient to consider these. As these now scale linearly with the time scale, stability conditions can be expressed in $z=\lambda h$ for $y'= λy$. Such results can be applied locally to non-linear systems. Step sizes that contradict the locality may invalidate the stability properties.

Yes, when discussing stability it is assumed that the implicit step equation is solved exactly.

"Never blows up" is for situations where the exact solution stays bounded in some neighborhood of the current base point. If the exact solution has a divergence, then numerical methods tend to follow that, even if not at the exact same time.

Arbitrarily large step sizes only apply to linear equations and systems, which also are the defining case for A-stability. There are approaches to define stability in general terms also for non-linear equations.

Usually the step size control of the method will reduce the step size when the number of Newton iterations becomes too large. Note that for practicality the implicit solver is a simplified Newton method, often with an approximate Jacobian. This still allows to maintain an error reduction by a factor $O(h^2)$, so if you start with a good predictor (for instance extrapolation from the last step), the first Newton step should reach the method order in the error order of the implicit equation. With the second Newton step the implicit error should be very small against the method step error, which indeed often is good enough. However, this only applies to small-dimensional medium hard problems.

Doing a fixed number of Newton steps makes the method into an explicit method with a bounded stability region. To retain the character of an implicit method you need to control the convergence of the implicit solver. But 70 Newton steps is likely too large. Chances are that with half the step size the combined number of Newton iteration for the now two steps is much smaller.

Comment: Thank you for the very clear and detailed answer! This is *exactly* what I was looking for. I've been mulling over this for months now so huge thanks for writing this down :)

Comment: Lutz, do I understand correctly that Backward Euler is not unconditionally stable for nonlinear equation systems (even if an arbitrarily large number of iterations is allowed per time step)?

Comment: For non-linear equations the step equation $y_{n+1}-hf(y_{n+1})=y_n$ can have multiple solutions, especially when the state $y$ is a vector. If the step is too large, the Newton iteration can become chaotic, failing to converge, or it converges to some random, far away solution. Only if $h$ is small enough will the exact value $y(t_{n+1})$ and the correct solution of the step equation be close to $y_n$, the Newton iteration remaining in this neighborhood.

Comment: Thank you! This has helped so much.

Comment: @Lutz_Lehmann, could you say how decreasing the step size would help the Newton iterator if it is struggling? Is it that the reduced step size allows for a better linear approximation of the nonlinear equations being solved?

Comment: Also, @Lutz_Lehman, could you say how increasing the complexity of the system would impact the convergence of the Newton iterator? Suppose the system contains a block of coupled nonlinear algebraic equations that have to be solved simultaneously (e.g., they form an algebraic loop). Would a larger "algebraic block" require more iterations or be more prone to convergence errors? Why?

Comment: Every variant of the Newton method has a region around a root where it behaves mostly like the theoretical model, which is called local convergence. The theoretical bounds are often rather pessimistic relative to the practical reality. Outside this region you get the typical problems of global convergence, mainly large chaotic jumps. Counter measures increase the complexity heavily. Reducing the step size increases the likelihood of staying inside the region of local convergence. For step size zero this is trivial, so there is a segment of small step sizes with this property.

Comment: Increasing the complexity of the system such as dimension or degree (for some suitable estimate in non-algebraic systems) will reduce the size of the regions of convergence. Any structure in the system can have an effect in the other direction, for instance by encoding dimensions that are purely or mainly linear (might require a linear transformation in domain and range), which reduces the effective dimension. This all is heuristics, one would have to properly define such classes of ODE and study these effects concretely.

Comment: Thank you for the insight! Suppose you have a large DAE system for which an implicit solver with a Newton iterator fails to converge. Could you increase the odds that the solver will find a valid solution by splitting the system of equations into smaller systems of equations each handled by a separate solver with a separate Newton iterator (coupled with appropriate algebraic constraints between the systems)? Or would you expect this to have no effect on the solvability of your model?